# When the source sheet is all filtered out, getting the values from of the *target* sheet fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to copy content from a filtered sheet to another.

When the source sheet is empty, getting the values from of the *target* sheet fails.

How can I bypass this?

Exception: This operation is not supported on a range with a filtered out row.

[image]

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue of `When the source sheet is empty, getting the values from of the target sheet fails.`?

Comment: I cannot rrproduce your issue, maybe you can provide a sample spreadsheet with a bound script?